# AD find Members on other domain

Tags: java, active-directory, jndi

But i have to do a search with ldap (on java) on an Active Directory (Win server 2008 R2 - is not important). I use the JNDI API to make binding and searches.

Now i have the following situation:
domain.com   (Root)

- Administration (Group)

  - user1
  - user2
  - user3
- Workers (Group)

  - user3
  - user4

I set up my search with domain: domain.com, and as filter i set up Administration, so that i pick up only administration User. The problem is if user3 is defined under workers and not on Administration (I mean that i show the Group properties and under the tab Members i have: user1, user2, user3) user3 was not found.....(at the end I have to import these 3 user in a other system).

How can i get easy and fast this user3 from the other domain without change a lot of filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end i found only this solution: For every member that is on the group, but declared outside, I made the search changing the domain every time.